# Convert image to string without losing data in c++

Tags: c++

I am sending data from my C++ client to C# WCF service where it accepts JSON data.

We need to send an image to WCF service by converting it to a JSON string, but while converting image (jpg/jpeg) it has some null characters inside a string (`\0`) so the string is getting terminated when converting `std::string` to `char*` and I am able to send only part of the string to service. Is there way that I can convert the image to string (`const char *`) without having null characters in it so that I can send all the image data (as `char*`) without loosing any data?

The available function from C++ client is:

```
httpClient.POST("ServiceName", const char* data, "ContentType")
```

Comment: Convert to base64

Comment: You should not create a "string" from the raw binary data. Instead you use some encoding scheme that is textual but can handle arbitrary binary data. One such common encoding scheme is [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: Convert the data to hex or base64 first.

Comment: use an array of uchar of known size

Comment: Converting to base64 has worked. Thanks